# How to check if date in a cell + 5 = today? (Google Apps Script + Google Sheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to get a date from a cell, add 5 days to it, and check if that date is today. Here's what I've tried:

```
function test() {
  sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var today = new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0));

  var weekStartDate = sheet.getRange('B5').getValue().getTime();
    var newDate1 = new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0));
    var newDate5 = new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0));
    newDate1.setTime(weekStartDate + (1*24*60*60*1000));
    newDate5.setTime(weekStartDate + (5*24*60*60*1000));

  if(newDate5==today){
    var answer = 'Yes';
  } else{
    var answer = 'No';
  }

   Logger.log(today);
   Logger.log(newDate1);
   Logger.log(newDate5);
   Logger.log(answer);
}
```

The log shows:

```
11:29:59 AM Info    Wed Jul 21 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2021
11:29:59 AM Info    Sat Jul 17 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2021
11:29:59 AM Info    Wed Jul 21 00:00:00 GMT-04:00 2021
11:29:59 AM Info    No
```

How do I get "answer" to return "Yes"?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRpsj.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare two dates, we use values of these dates. This means if you changed `newDate5 == today` with `newDate5.valueOf() == today.valueOf()` it will return `Yes`.

Here is a simplified version of your code:

```
function test() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var today = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0).valueOf(); 
  var dateToCompare= new Date(sheet.getRange('B5').getValue()).valueOf();
  var dayInMs = 24*60*60*1000

  Logger.log(today);
  Logger.log(dateToCompare);
  Logger.log(today == dateToCompare + 5*dayInMs);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case

```
function myFunction() {
  // date from cell 'A1'
  var date = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').getValue();

  // today
  var today = new Date();

  // function to add 5 days to a date
  const five_days_later = (d) => new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() + 5));

  // function to compare two dates
  const if_same_date = (d1, d2) => d1.getDate() == d2.getDate() &&
    d1.getMonth() == d2.getMonth() && d1.getYear() == d2.getYear();

  // test
  Logger.log(if_same_date(five_days_later(date), today));
}
```

```js
var now = new Date();
var then = new Date("2021-07-16");

const to_str = x => '' + x.getYear() + x.getMonth() + x.getDate();
const if_same_date = (d1, d2) => to_str(d1) == to_str(d2);
const plus_days = (date, gap) => new Date(date.valueOf() + gap*24*60*60*1000);

console.log(if_same_date(now, plus_days(then, 5)));
```