# How to Hide Columns dated before 3 days ago

Tags: google-apps-script

I've adapted the code below which should hide dates in row8 before today, but how can I adapt it to hiding dates that are 7 days old like today(-7) so to speak.

Thanks

```
function showAll() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.unhideColumn(sheet.getDataRange());
    ss.toast("All columns unhidden.");
}
function hidePast() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    // Acquire the 1st row of all used columns as an array of arrays.
    var datelist = sheet.getSheetValues(8, 5, 5, sheet.getLastColumn());

    // Drop the hours, minutes, seconds, etc. from today.
    var now = new Date();
    var today = new Date(Date.UTC(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDate()));

    // Inspect the datelist and compare to today. Start from the rightmost
    // column (assuming the dates are chronologically increasing).
    var col = datelist[0].length;
    while(--col >= 0) {
        var then = new Date(datelist[0][col]);
        if(then < today) {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Bounds check, and convert col into a 1-base index (instead of 0-base).
    if(++col < 1) return;

    // col now is the first index where the date is before today.
    // Increment again, as these are 2-column merged regions (and
    // the value is stored in the leftmost range). If not incremented,
    // (i.e. hiding only part of a merged range), spreadsheet errors will occur.
    sheet.hideColumn(sheet.getRange(8, 5, 5, ++col));
    ss.toast("Hid all the columns before today.");
}
```

Comment: Use Date().valueOf() or Date().getTime() to compare datetimes numerically.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68472494/how-to-check-if-date-in-a-cell-5-today-google-apps-script-google-sheets/

Answer (score 1):

```
var day = 24*60*60*1000; // number of milliseconds in one day.
var date_from_cell = new Date(datelist[0][col]).setHours(0,0,0,0);
var seven_days_ago = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0) - 7 * day;

if(date_from_cell < seven_days_ago) { 
    // do stuff
}
```

`date.setHours(0,0,0,0)` gets you the date with zero for hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds. It's need if you want to compare dates without hours, minutes, etc.