# Convert two dates to String and compare them

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to compare two dates and make something if they are equal.

The first date come from a google sheet. The cell format is a date and the localization is at France (GMT+1).
The second date come from an HTML form date field filled by the user.

I want to compare the strings in the yyyy--MM--dd format, so I used the function Utilities.format().
When I display the string values, everything seems to be okay.

But when the string comparison doesn't work. It's probably a conversion issue. I did some tests, nothin works.

Here's a part of my code

```
//...
  } else {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(formObject.licenseExpiration); // Works. Displays yyyy-MM--dd
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(Utilities.formatDate(sheetDataRangeValues[0][7], "GMT+1", "yyyy-MM-dd")); // Works. Displays yyyy-MM--dd
    if (Utilities.formatDate(formObject.licenseExpiration, "GMT+1", "yyyy-MM-dd") == Utilities.formatDate(sheetDataRangeValues[0][7], "GMT+1", "yyyy-MM-dd") || formObject.licenseExpiration == "") {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("It works !");
    }
//...
```

Thanks for your help.

**Edit:**

HTML

```
<form id="filterForm" onSubmit="handleFormSubmitFilter(this)">
      <label for="licenseExpiration">License Expiration</label><br/>
      <input type="date" id="licenseExpiration" name="licenseExpiration"><br/><br/>
</form>

<script>
    function preventFormSubmitFilter() {

        var formsFilter = document.querySelectorAll('FormFilter');

        for (var i; i < formsFilter.length; i++) {
            formsFilter[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmitFilter);
  
    function handleFormSubmitFilter(formObject) {
        google.script.run.processFormFilter(formObject);
        document.getElementById("filterForm").reset();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Here are something alike: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68472494/how-to-check-if-date-in-a-cell-5-today-google-apps-script-google-sheets/68473035#68473035 Probably you need to add `.valueOf()` to the dates

Comment: Use valueOf() or getTime() methods and you can compare numerically or you can build strings with Utilities.formatDate() or basic string methods with or without literals.  I personally use valueOf() a lot more than anything else and I compare numerically.

Comment: One more variant to compare dates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68541576/how-to-hide-columns-dated-before-3-days-ago/68543847#68543847 with `.setHours(0,0,0,0)` method.

Comment: I tried to use the valueOf() function. The **sheet** date is well converted but the **form date** is not recognized.
I tried to resolve this issue with new Date(). No results.

All of these issues are probably caused by the form data.
It returns a string but I can do nothing with. For example, this condition doesn't work
`if (formObject.licenseExpiration == "2024-28-03")`

I edited my topic for more informations about the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the best result you need pass the "raw" date in a new Date object. Then use the Utilities to convert this to a string. Tip: use console.log() to (or better, the debugger) see your output.

```
  const licenseDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(formObject.licenseExpiration), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
  const sheetDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(sheetDataRangeValues[0][7]), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-DD");
  if (sheetDate == licenseDate || formObject.licenseExpiration == "") {
    console.log('it works')
  }
```