# Execute For loop if the date in row 3 matches criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help creating a function that executes a For loop when the date in row 3 equals today or today - 3. I already have the For loop done, but it can be written more efficiently (I'm new to this). I don't know how to create the IF statement for the date search in a single row.

Summary:
If a date in row 3 is today's date or 3 days before today's date, I want a For loop to send an email based on the data in the rest of the spreadsheet. I also need to grab the date from row 3 and include it in the body of the email. The current method I have is very inefficient. Especially since I will need to add a lot more dates in row 3.

I'd like to:

1. replace the multiple IF statements at the end of the script with a single IF statement
2. not have to use any var WeekX
3. only use one var subject and var msg

Any help is appreciated!

[Screenshot of Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaeJf.jpg)

```
function Auto_Email() {

var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var data = sSheet.getRange(4, 1, sSheet.getLastRow(), sSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();  

  var Files1 = DriveApp.getFilesByName('file.pdf');
  var file1; 
  if (Files1.hasNext()) {
   file1 = Files1.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF);
   } else {
    throw new Error("No file");
 }
  
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
    var row = data[i]
    var values = data2[i]
    var Email = row[8]
    var ccEmail = row[9]
    var bcc = ""
    var sig = "";

    
    var Week1 = sSheet.getRange("K3").getValues();
    var Week2 = sSheet.getRange("M3").getValues();
    var Week3 = sSheet.getRange("O3").getValues();
    var Week4 = sSheet.getRange("Q3").getValues();
    var Week5 = sSheet.getRange("S3").getValues();
    var Week6 = sSheet.getRange("U3").getValues();
    
    var subject1 = "Week of " + Week1 
    var msg1 = "Good morning, " + row[1]+ "."
              +"<br/><br/> Please submit your results for the week of " + Week1 + " to your supervisor by the end of the week." 
              +"<br><br>Thank you,"
              +sig;

    var subject2 = "Week of " + Week2 
    var msg2 = "Good morning, " + row[1]+ "."
              +"<br/><br/> Please submit your results for the week of " + Week2 + " to your supervisor by the end of the week."
              +sig;

    var subject3 = "Week of " + Week3 
    var msg3 = "Good morning, " + row[1]+ "."
              +"<br/><br/> Please submit your results for the week of " + Week3 + " to your supervisor by the end of the week." 
              +sig;

    var subject4 = "Week of " + Week4 
    var msg4 = "Good morning, " + row[1]+ "."
              +"<br/><br/> Please submit your results for the week of " + Week4 + " to your supervisor by the end of the week."
              +sig;

    var subject5 = "Week of " + Week5 
    var msg5 = "Good morning, " + row[1]+ "."
              +"<br/><br/> Please submit your results for the week of " + Week5 + " to your supervisor by the end of the week."
              +sig;

    var subject6 = "Week of " + Week6 
    var msg6 = "Good morning, " + row[1]+ "."
              +"<br/><br/> Please submit your results for the week of " + Week6 + " to your supervisor by the end of the week." 
              +sig;
  
    
    if(row[22] === 3 || row[22] === 0 && row[8] != '') {
      GmailApp.sendEmail(Email,subject1,'',{
                         htmlBody: msg1,
                         cc:ccEmail,
                         bcc: bcc,
                         attachments: [file1]});}
    
      if(row[23] === 3 || row[23] === 0 && row[8] != '') {
      GmailApp.sendEmail(Email,subject2,'',{
                         htmlBody: msg2,
                         cc:ccEmail,
                         bcc: bcc,
                         attachments: [file1]});}
     
      if(row[24] === 3 || row[24] === 0 && row[8] != '') {
      GmailApp.sendEmail(Email,subject3,'',{
                         htmlBody: msg3,
                         cc:ccEmail,
                         bcc: bcc,
                         attachments: [file1]});}
     
      if(row[25] === 3 || row[25] === 0 && row[8] != '') {
      GmailApp.sendEmail(Email,subject4,'',{
                         htmlBody: msg4,
                         cc:ccEmail,
                         bcc: bcc,
                         attachments: [file1]});}
     
      if(row[26] === 3 || row[26] === 0 && row[8] != '') {
      GmailApp.sendEmail(Email,subject5,'',{
                         htmlBody: msg5,
                         cc:ccEmail,
                         bcc: bcc,
                         attachments: [file1]});}
     
      if(row[27] === 3 || row[27] === 0 && row[8] != '') {
      GmailApp.sendEmail(Email,subject6,'',{
                         htmlBody: msg6,
                         cc:ccEmail,
                         bcc: bcc,
                         attachments: [file1]});}
     
    
  }
  }
```

Comment: Here is a couple examples how to check dates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68472494/how-to-check-if-date-in-a-cell-5-today-google-apps-script-google-sheets/

Comment: Please focus your question to a single problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example